# Me ajudem! linguagem C

Tags: c

Estou começando agora e queria saber o que tem de errado, o programa abre, coloco os valores e ao clicar em 'enter' nada acontece, por favor me ajudem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    float bc, ab, ac, a, b, c, d;
    printf("\nEntre com quatro numero:\n\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f", & a, & b, & c, & d);
    bc = b - c;
    if (bc < 0)
        bc = bc * -1;
    ab = a - b;
    if (ab < 0)
        ab = ab * -1;
    ac = a - c;
    if (ac < 0)
        ac = ac * -1;
    if ((bc < a && a < b + a) && (ab < b && b < a + b) && (ac < c && c < a + c))
        if (a == b && b == c)
            printf("\n Trinagulo \n\n");
        else if (a == b || b == c || c == a)
        printf("\n Triangulo isosceles\n\n");
    else printf("\n Triangulo escaleno\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o código? Por que digitar 4 números se você usa só três? E que valores você informou? Tentou com valores diferentes? Pesquise sobre como fazer um teste de mesa.

Comment: Uma atenção a forma como cria o titulo da pergunta. Evitar palavras como ajudar por favor, ou urgente! Os moderadores geralmente negativam perguntas com este tipo de titulo. Seja direito e escreva o código completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando tem um encadeamento de if/else dentro de outro if/else é preciso usar chaves para evitar o problema de else ambíguo, onde o compilador não sabe se o else pertence ao if interno ou externo, as chaves consertam isso.

Não é preciso criar tantas variáveis para esse algoritmo, e a logica deles não está correta.

Para verificar se os segmentos podem formar um triangulo é preciso saber se cada segmento é menor que a soma entre os outros dois segmentos. Se sim, verifica se os segmentos são iguais (equilátero), diferentes (escaleno) ou iguais com uma diferença (isósceles). Se não, os segmentos não podem formar um triangulo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Insira 3 valores: ");

  // C não inicializa as variáveis, portanto elas devem ser inicializadas manualmente.
  float a = 0.0f, b = 0.0f, c = 0.0f;
  scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

  // Cada segmento precisa ser menor que a soma dos outros dois.
  if(a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b) {
    printf("Triangulo: ");

    if(a == b && b == c) {
      // Segmentos iguais: Equilátero.
      printf("Equilátero\n");
    }else if (a != b && b != c && c != a) {
      // Segmentos diferentes: Escaleno.
      printf("Escaleno\n");
    }else {
      // Por dedução se não é Equilátero e nem Escaleno é Isósceles.
      printf("Isósceles\n");
    }
  }else {
    printf("Não é possível formar um triangulo!\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja mais uma questão de familiaridade com a programação.
Dá uma atenção a edentação e aos colchetes. Fora isso, parabéns pela bom trabalho.

**Código** em [execução](https://code.sololearn.com/cge9Xy1LYv0N)

**Código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    float bc, ab, ac, a, b, c;

    a = 0.0f;
    b = 0.0f;
    c = 0.0f;

    printf("\nEntre com tres numero:\n\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    bc = b - c;

    if (bc < 0)  bc = bc * -1;

    ab = a - b;

    if (ab < 0)  ab = ab * -1;

    ac = a - c;

    if (ac < 0)  ac = ac * -1;

    if ( (bc < a && a < b + a) && (ab < b && b < a + b) && (ac < c && c < a + c) ){

        if (a == b && b == c)
            printf("\n Trinagulo \n\n");
        else if (a == b || b == c || c == a)
            printf("\n Triangulo isosceles\n\n");
       else 
        printf("\n Triangulo escaleno\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que você não testou esse código, ele não está produzindo os resultados corretos, você está declarando uma variável que não é usada e o scanf está lendo uma variável a mais na lista.

Comment: Correção realizada.